# Docusign INVALID_REQUEST_BODY after adding eventNotification

Tags: php, json, docusignapi

While trying to add [webhook status](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/webhook-status) to a nicely working Docusign integration API, it started to give me a the error INVALID_REQUEST_BODY.

As I'm using the PHP API, I'm not writing the JSON payload myself, Docusign PHP package is responsible for serializing the thing, but, it says INVALID_REQUEST_BODY, pointing to here:

```
"eventNotification":[{"url":"https:\/\/xxx.yyyy.zzz.com\/docusign\/webhook",
                    ^
```

I also tried to remove everything else, sending only the url parameter. Tried to change the URL, sending only a domain. Nothing worked. If I send the event notification I get the error, if I don't send it, everything works fine.

And the Docusign PHP package raises exceptions if you send wrongly named items to it, so, I'm also sure the EventNotification model is pretty much correct.

Here's the full error message, without sensitive data:

```
[DEBUG] HTTP Request body  ~BEGIN~
{"documents":[{"documentId":1,"name":"XXXXXXXXXX.pdf","documentBase64":"XXXXXXXX="}],"recipients":{"signers":[{"tabs":{"signHereTabs":[{"documentId":1,"recipientId":1,"pageNumber":1,"anchorString":"recipient_signature"}]},"name":"xxxxxxxxx","email":"xx@xxxxxxxx.com","recipientId":1,"clientUserId":XXXX}]},"eventNotification":[{"url":"https:\/\/xxx.yyyy.zzz.com\/docusign\/webhook","loggingEnabled":"true"}],"status":"sent","emailSubject":"XXXXXX - XXXXXX Certification","brandId":"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"}
~END~
* Hostname demo.docusign.net was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 162.248.186.25...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to demo.docusign.net (162.248.186.25) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate: demo.docusign.net
* Server certificate: Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3
* Server certificate: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
> POST /restApi/v2/accounts/XXXXXX/envelopes HTTP/1.1
Host: demo.docusign.net
User-Agent: PHP-Swagger/2.0.0
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"dev@xxxx.com","Password":"xxxxxxx","IntegratorKey":"XXX-XXXXXXXX-XXX-XXXX-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"}
X-DocuSign-SDK: PHP
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 3981
Expect: 100-continue

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Length: 725
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< X-DocuSign-TraceToken: c227xxxx
< Date: Wed, 05 Apr 2017 00:13:16 GMT
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
<
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host demo.docusign.net left intact
[DEBUG] HTTP Response body ~BEGIN~
{
  "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_BODY",
  "message": "The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'API_REST.Models.v2.eventNotification' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath 'eventNotification', line 1, position 3790."
}
```

So what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incorrectly using the eventNotification parameter as an array.

The following should work. I have removed the square braces `[]`

```
"eventNotification": {
        "url": "https:\/\/xxx.yyyy.zzz.com\/docusign\/webhook",
        "loggingEnabled": "true"
 }
```

Here is your complete request

```
{
    "documents": [ { "documentId": 1, "name": "XXXXXXXXXX.pdf", "documentBase64": "XXXXXXXX=" } ],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [
                        {
                            "documentId": 1,
                            "recipientId": 1,
                            "pageNumber": 1,
                            "anchorString": "recipient_signature"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "name": "xxxxxxxxx",
                "email": "xx@xxxxxxxx.com",
                "recipientId": 1,
                "clientUserId": XXXX
            }
        ]
    },
    "eventNotification": {
        "url": "https:\/\/xxx.yyyy.zzz.com\/docusign\/webhook",
        "loggingEnabled": "true"
    },
    "status": "sent",
    "emailSubject": "XXXXXX - XXXXXX Certification",
    "brandId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Comment: You were absolutely right and it works fine now, thank you! But is this information available in the web interface (https://appdemo.docusign.com/documents) somehow? As Docusign is not hitting my webhook URL, I would like to check if the url and statuses are correctly stored in the envelope.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43222592/1219543) for troubleshooting connect issues.