# Docusign not hitting webhook URL

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm trying to use [webhooks](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/webhook-status), but no events are being sent to my application via the webhook url. So far I was able to configure and send correctly envelopes with enough information to monitor status, but when things changes in the envelopes, nothing happens, I mean, no requests are made to my webhook URL, at all.

My app is doing good, so if I manually hit (GET) https://subdomain.app.com/docusign/webhook, it works fine and it shows both on my app log and Nginx log. But viewing, signing and completing documents/envelopes are not generating events to the webhook url.

I noticed that, in the examples, the events are capitalized for recientEvents, but not for envelopeEvents, is this right?

Is there anything else to be configured?

Is is possible to see this information in the Docusign web interface (https://account-d.docusign.com/logout#/username)? I would like to check if this data is correctly set in the envelope.

Here's the envelope request (minus some data):

```
{
    "documents": [{
        "documentId": 1,
        "name": "XXXXXXXXX.pdf",
        "documentBase64": "XXXXXXX"
    }],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [{
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [{
                    "documentId": 1,
                    "recipientId": 1,
                    "pageNumber": 1,
                    "anchorString": "recipient_signature"
                }]
            },
            "name": "XXXXXX",
            "email": "XXXX@XXXX.co",
            "recipientId": 1,
            "clientUserId": XXXX
        }]
    },
    "eventNotification": {
        "url": "https:\/\/subdomain.app.com\/docusign\/webhook",
        "loggingEnabled": "true",
        "envelopeEvents": [{
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "sent"
        }, {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "delivered"
        }, {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "completed"
        }, {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "declined"
        }, {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "voided"
        }, {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "sent"
        }, {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "sent"
        }],
        "recipientEvents": [{
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "Sent"
        }, {
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "Delivered"
        }, {
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "Completed"
        }, {
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "Declined"
        }, {
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "AuthenticationFailed"
        }, {
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "AutoResponded"
        }]
    },
    "status": "sent",
    "emailSubject": "XXXXXX",
    "brandId": "XXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

EDIT:

Entering Connect -> Log/Failures looks like the system is not really performing as it should, because sometimes I get

[image]
[image]

And some other times I get an empty list. Going in the publish option, when it's working I get a list of documents/envelopes, and I see the last envelope I sent there, which looks fine.

Comment: I can't really tell why the system is throwing the error in some instances. But if you are seeing you envelope details in the connect logs then that means you are creating your envelope with the correct eventNotification parameters. I have updated my answer to include information related to the [connectEvents](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Connect/ConnectEvents/) api's.

Answer (score 1):

You can view your recent connect logs/failures at the [Docusign Admin](https://admindemo.docusign.com/connect) web application. See instructions to use the Admin site [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-welcome-to-administration)

If your connect messages were not sent, to the listener URL you provided, they should show up in the failures section.

***API*** : You can also view your connect logs/failure using the [connectEvents](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Connect/ConnectEvents/) api's

Here is some [documentation](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/connect.htm#Checking2) for troubleshooting connect issues.

The capitalization of status codes is not an issue. They are case insensitive.

Comment: Edited my question to provide some information on what I got from logs/failures.

Comment: So what do you do if the logs you mention show no failures at all, but webhooks still aren't being sent (except for embedded signings, where the webhook works *perfectly*)? I'm not setting a clientUserId, I have event notifications set up for envelopes and recipients, the NON-embedded signing itself works great from the emailed links even though no webhook gets triggered, and those logs show zilch after the Created_CreateAndSendEnvelope and Created_RequestRecipientToken sections... no errors, no failures, and no webhooks. So what's stopping the webhooks?

Comment: Can you provide some of your envelopeId's where the webhook events were not sent.

Comment: 107eb901-6fde-48d6-ab64-82fa170e796c (void now), and 
aabbea5f-cb2e-4505-910e-20bc87de260a (not void)

Comment: Here is the error message I am seeing .. `https://287.........sys.com/api/v1_0/docusign :: Error - The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.; The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.` Looks like your endpoint has an invalid certificate.

Comment: Then how does the *embedded* signing webhook come through okay? And the cert isn't "invalid," it's just self-signed. SSL certs aren't for identity verification, they're for encrypting communication channels, so a self-signed cert is exactly as secure as one issued by some "official" source. Docusign seriously doesn't allow self-signed certs? Is this some conspiracy Verisign or someone thought up?

Comment: Wait, I just checked. The cert doesn't expire for another month, and it was issued by COMODO CA Limited. So it isn't self-signed and it's valid, so what's up?

Comment: YOu checkout some of the docusign webhook [blog posts](https://www.docusign.com/blog/author/larrykluger/) and see if you have setup your webhooks correctly...  If that does not answer you can probably post a new question and someone from the community should be able to provide more insight.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154722/discussion-between-innovator-and-codingdawg).